# What's the difference between 'scribble' and 'draw'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

'SCRIBBLE' can be a piece of careless text +/or drawing while 'DRAW' is only drawing? Is it? In that way sometimes 'scribbling' can be used as a substitute for 'drawing'? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I think there's writing and there's drawing, but doing either carelessly can be scribbling; "I scribbled a note".  "I found a scribbled drawing."

Comment: It can also be used self-deprecatingly: "That? Oh, that's just one of my scribbles."

Comment: Thank you both! Now I think I understand. 'Scribble' is a word that hovers over both writing and drawing.

Answer (score 2):

*Scribble* usually refers to text, while a "**doodle**" is a pictorial scribble.